# How can I delete attachments from emails with Outlook, while keeping the email itself?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a lot of messages with attachments in Outlook, I need to remove only attachments, how can I do that? I have 10 000 of them, how to make it easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, there's no option to remove attachments of multiple emails at a time, but you can do it with VBA. Please refer to the following steps:

1.Create a folder and name it as "OLAttachments" in Documents;
[image]

2.Press **Alt+F11** to open the **VBA Editor**;

3.Expand the **Project1** > **Microsoft Outlook Objects**>**ThisOutlookSession**;

4.Copy and paste the following VBA code in the editing pane;

```
Public Sub ReplaceAttachmentsToLink()
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
Dim aMail As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim oAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim oSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim iCount As Long
Dim sFile As String
Dim sFolderPath As String
Dim sDeletedFiles As String
  
    ' Get the path to your My Documents folder
    sFolderPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
    On Error Resume Next
  
    ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
    Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  
    ' Get the collection of selected objects.
    Set oSelection = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection
  
    ' Set the Attachment folder.
    sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\OLAttachments"
  
     
    ' Check each selected item for attachments. If attachments exist,
    ' save them to the Temp folder and strip them from the item.
    For Each aMail In oSelection
  
    ' This code only strips attachments from mail items.
    ' If aMail.class=olMail Then
    ' Get the Attachments collection of the item.
    Set oAttachments = aMail.Attachments
    iCount = oAttachments.Count
      
        
    If iCount > 0 Then
      
        ' We need to use a count down loop for removing items
        ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
        ' confused and only every other item is removed.
          
        For i = iCount To 1 Step -1
          
            ' Save attachment before deleting from item.
            ' Get the file name.
            sFile = oAttachments.Item(i).FileName
              
            ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
            sFile = sFolderPath & "\" & sFile
              
            ' Save the attachment as a file.
            oAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile sFile
              
            ' Delete the attachment.
            oAttachments.Item(i).Delete
              
            'write the save as path to a string to add to the message
            'check for html and use html tags in link
            If aMail.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                sDeletedFiles = sDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & sFile & ">"
            Else
                sDeletedFiles = sDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
                sFile & "'>" & sFile & "</a>"
            End If
              
                          
        Next i
        'End If
              
       ' Adds the filename string to the message body and save it
       ' Check for HTML body
       If aMail.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
           aMail.Body = aMail.Body & vbCrLf & _
           "The file(s) were saved to " & sDeletedFiles
       Else
           aMail.HTMLBody = aMail.HTMLBody & "<p>" & _
           "The file(s) were saved to " & sDeletedFiles & "</p>"
       End If
        
       aMail.Save
       'sets the attachment path to nothing before it moves on to the next message.
       sDeletedFiles = ""
     
       End If
    Next 'end aMail
      
ExitSub:
  
Set oAttachments = Nothing
Set aMail = Nothing
Set oSelection = Nothing
Set objApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

5.Save the code;

6.On Outlook top, click down arrow>**More Commands…**;

[image]

7.Choose the macros and add to the Quick Access Folders>Ok;
[image]

Then the macro will be displayed in the top;

[image]

8.Choose the emails that you want to remove the attachments(hold the Ctrl key and click scattered emails, or hold the shift key to choose the adjacent emails)

9.Click the macro will be displayed in the top, and then the attachments of the emails will be removed to the OLAttachments folder.

Hope the above help!

Comment: One of my favorite SO answers!!! Code + instructions + it just works.  I've needed this for years thank you!  If anyone uses this remove the ON ERROR RESUME NEXT!  Since I did not create the OLAttachments folder in the right place, it failed to save the files and just plowed-on and deleted the attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is a proprietary data base.

I have not seen a program that will remove only attachments, although it is easy to do manually.

Accordingly, your goal is not really achievable.

"Easy" Way forward:

Archive old mail (say everything older than 1 year).

Archives can be moved off to a backup system.

Now, remove Attachments as necessary on Current emails.

This will work well (I do this) and reduce Outlook data storage space needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the outlook addon interface using C# you can delete attachments I think.

**Note: You're gonna have to make this yourself with C#** (or visual basic but... like... I would recommend using C#)

[Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577904/can-i-read-an-outlook-2003-2007-pst-file-in-c) on getting a PST file but the same-ish method can be used to select an account.

[Here's a link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.folder) to the docs on a folder object. This will let you iterate through a folder and/or get subfolders.

The PST link will also show you how to iterate over mailItems (emails).

[Here's a link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem) to the mailItem documentation. A mailItem has an `Attachments` property which is some sort of container of attachments.

[Here's a link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachments) to the `Attachments` documentation. There's a `Remove` method that will do what you want I think.